# My text is not going right under my header

Tags: html

I was trying to add my text right under my header but it gets squished at the edge of the  screen. Code:

```html
<h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white;
           display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 64px;">
  header

  <div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white;
           display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 14px;">
    text that needs to be under the header
  </div>
</h1>
```

I tried removing the div but then the text goes on top of the text below it. I'm trying to get it to be right under my header.

Comment: Remove the display:flex

Answer (score 1):

your mistakes are,

1. tags like h1 or p are only to be child, you can not use them as parent ( I don't know why it didn't showed you any errors )
   2.when you use flex , it takes flex-direction:raw as deafult, you will have to add it as "flex-direction:column"

```html
<div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white;
           display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 64px;" >
header
<div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white;
           display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 14px;" >
text that needs to be under the header
</div>
</div>
```

just do this and you will be all good!

hope you understand...

Comment: Yes, but I want the text to be right under my header.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean, but why don't you move the div outside the h1-tag:

```html
<h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 64px;">
  header
</h1>
<div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; color: white; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; font-size: 14px;">
  text that needs to be under the header
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y5umnoz/